# Can't access JWT from cookies or header

Tags: node.js, authentication, jwt

I've can create the the JWT tokens and send them in a cookie. But I can't access the token from either the header or the cookie from my frontend. This then becomes a issue when I try to authenticate a user to use routes. I know that you should only use cookies or headers but I'm just trying to make head way on this.

```
require("dotenv").config();

const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const bcryptjs = require("bcryptjs");
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'); 
const { check, validationResult } = require("express-validator");

const User = require("../models/userSchema");

const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

function asyncHandler(callback) {
  return async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      await callback(req, res, next);
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
}

router.post( "/login", asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    const userBody = req.body;
    console.log(userBody.password);
    const user = await User.findOne({ emailAddress: req.body.emailAddress });
    // console.log(user.password);

    if (userBody && user) {
      console.log(user);
      const authenticated = bcryptjs.compare(userBody.password, user.password);
      console.log(authenticated);

      if (authenticated) {
        console.log("match");
        const accessToken = jwt.sign(user.toJSON(), process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, { expiresIn: 86400 });

        res.cookie("token", accessToken, { httpOnly: true, maxAge: 86400 });

        res.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+ accessToken); 

        res.json({ 
          user: user,
          accessToken: accessToken,
          })
          .send()

      } else {
        res.status(403).send({ error: "Login failed: Please try again" }).end();
      }
    } else {
      res.status(403).send({ error: "Login failed: Please try again" }).end();
    }
  })
);

function authenticateUser(req, res, next) {

  let token =
    req.body.token ||
    req.query.token ||
    req.headers["x-access-token"] ||
    req.headers["Authorization"] ||
    req.headers["authorization"] ||
    req.cookies.token;

  console.log(token);

  if (!token) {
    return res.status(403).send({ auth: false, message: "No token provided." });
  }

  jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, function (error, user) {
    if (error) {
      return res.status(500).send({ auth: false, message: error });
    } else {
      console.log(token);
      console.log(req.user);
      next();
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're sending json in response I assume you're using a client for the frontend (react/angular/vue)  which means that `httpOnly` cookie won't be accessible through the client. also `setHeaders`. A solution would be storing the token in localStorage and sending it in headers. in axios for example

Login:

```
axios.post('loginRoute', { email: email, password: password })
  .then(res => {
    localStorage.setItem('jwt', res.data.accessToken);
    // do something
  })
  .catch((err => {
    // do something for error
  }));
```

API that requires auth

```
axios.get('route', {
  headers: {
    Authorization: localStorage.getItem('jwt'),
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
  }
})
  .then(res => {
    // do something
  });
```